# Drupal Add Media button is not showing up on editor

Tags: media

I have installed the media module and uploaded videos. 
But I don't see the Add media button on the editor to browse and insert the videos from the library. 
Is that it should be enabled ?

Comment: Which editor are you using? and Drupal version?

Comment: Drupal Version 7.16 . How do I check which editor used? I guess ckeditor

Comment: @develkar  ckeditor..

Comment: Are you using CKEditor alongwith the WYSIWYG module?
Can you see `admin/config/content/wysiwyg/profile/`?

Comment: @develkar I installed the WYSIWYG module along with CKEDITOR..Now I can see the Add Media.. Thanks..

Comment: This link will be helpful in case you are installing the latest ckeditor and having issue with the versions http://www.webopius.com/content/717/how-to-get-ckeditor-4-x-working-with-the-drupal-7-wysiwyg-module